# Trying to Start Email App with Double-Tap on a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, gesture-recognition

I am creating a simple master-detail application where I want the user to be able to double-tap the details view screen and have the default email application dialogue open from the device.  Attached below is my TopicDetalsFrament.java file.  Please help me understand why the OnDoubleTapListener code doesn't work.

```
public class TopicDetailFragment extends Fragment implements OnDoubleTapListener
{
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
 * represents.
 */
public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

/**
 * The topic content this fragment is presenting.
 */
private TopicArrayContent.TopicArrayItem mItem;

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public TopicDetailFragment() 
{

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) 
    {
        // Load the content specified by the fragment arguments. 
        mItem = TopicArrayContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_topic_detail, container, false);

    // Show the Scriptures content as text in a TextView.
    if (mItem != null) 
    {           
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.topic_scripture1)).setText(mItem.scripture1);
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.topic_scripture2)).setText(mItem.scripture2);
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.topic_scripture3)).setText(mItem.scripture3);
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.topic_scripture4)).setText(mItem.scripture4);
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.topic_scripture5)).setText(mItem.scripture5);
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.topic_scripture6)).setText(mItem.scripture6);
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.topic_scripture7)).setText(mItem.scripture7);
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.topic_name)).setText(mItem.topicName);
    }
    return rootView;        

}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[] { "Enter recipient's email address" });
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body of email");
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(TopicDetailFragment.this.getActivity(),
                "There are no email clients installed.",         Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}   

}
```

Thanks very much for any help /suggestions you can give,

SonCoder

Comment: I find a lot of info on how to do this on an Activity, but not much about implementing on a Fragment. I am a beginner, however, so still much to learn. Anyone have any ideas? Is there a better way with examples/tutorials you can point to?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you simply did not register for any events. Implementing the interface does not magically deliver you the tap events. You'll have to install the fragment as a listener.

See the [gesture detection training](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) and set up the gesture detector with your fragment as the callback in the onCreate method.

---

Apart from that: IMHO, this pattern is not good practice on Android. The user will not know that he has to double tap the screen to perform an action. Why not provide a clickable e-mail address (see the default Android People application), or action bar menu entry?

Comment: Appreciate the tip about using a clickable email address.  I'll look into that as a preferred alternative.  Also grateful for the link to "gesture detection training".

Comment: Glad to be able to help :)